# getting Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' (0x1096d26b8) to 'NSMutableArray in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I'm working in **Swift 3.0** and in which I'm using **Core Data** to store info. I'm getting user details in `NSManagedObject` and so in order to display data I want it to convert in `NSMutableArray` but it shows a run time error,yet it is working fine with `NSArray`

I'm working hard to find this error but not getting the exact issue.

Any kind of help will surely be appreciated!!!

Comment: Why to convert in NSMutableAraay ? You can achieve those using "Array" of swift.

Comment: Hi actually i m new to swift ,came from Objective C background,so i m not getting to this "Array swift" usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can perform all the operation using "**Array**" which **NSMutableArray** can do.

```
    let strConstant = " Wolverine"
    let birthDate = "17/5/91"
    let birthYear = 1991
    let currentyear = 2016
```

Suppose above are the values which we need to handle with "Array" and "NSMutableArray" in Swift3.0

So below I have create a basic operations which you can perform using Array and NSMutableArray both and in both the cases Output will be same.

You can Put the Coding part in any playground, and you can which line perform which task.

> Handle operation with **Swift Array** :

```
var newRatingList = [Any]()
newRatingList.append(strConstant)
newRatingList.append(birthDate)
newRatingList.append((currentyear - birthYear))
newRatingList.last
newRatingList[1] = "18/5/91"
newRatingList
```

> Handle operation with **NSMutableArray** :

```
var mutableArray = NSMutableArray()
mutableArray.add(strConstant)
mutableArray.add(birthDate)
mutableArray.add((currentyear - birthYear))
mutableArray.lastObject
mutableArray.replaceObject(at: 1, with: "18/05/91")
```

To understand how array works you can also refer the below link :
https://makeapppie.com/2016/06/23/how-to-use-arrays-in-swift-3-0/

**Now related to your question consider this is a example**

```
var locations  = [Locations]() // Where Locations = your NSManaged Class

var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Locations")
locations = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Locations]

// Then you can use your properties.
for location in locations {
  print(location.name)   
}
```

In above example you will get a **Swift Array** of Locations. So by applying For-in loop you can get the Individual properties and if yo want to convert it into array then you can do something like this,

```
var a = NSMutableArray()
for location in locations {
    var dictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
    dictionary["name"] = location.name
    dictionary["location"] = location.location
    a.addObject(dictionary)
}
```

In the end, you will get "a" NSMutableArray which contain dictionaries.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome and detailed answer which i needed a lot,thanks for ur help **@Wolverine**

Comment: @priyanshu Welcome..Please mark it as answer it it has solve your queries. Thanks.